# Restrict SFTP users to different directories

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp, account-restrictions

How can I restrict some users/groups to some directories? I mean different users, different directories.

- What I have: Ubuntu 14.
- Experience with Ubuntu: Just started.

What I have tried:

1. I read [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04). This was working till a bit extent, what the problem is that, the user can do things only in his folder/directory, which is read/write and edit, but the user can also go elsewhere, and open files and copy scripts from there, which can be risky as while having a game server on the VPS. He can't delete/edit or add files but can VIEW files other than his directory.
2. And, then [this page](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/). This worked fine, but the problem is, I couldn't find a way to add more users to different directories. Like, I could only add one user to directory which was specified in sshd_config file. There is only one directory which can be restricted for one group. I want it to be flexible, able to add different users to different directories... groups.

Here is what I'm talking about: `sshd_config`

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group shooter
ChrootDirectory /home/shooter/shooter/mods
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

That `shooter` group can only access that `ChrootDirectory`. If I add different users to that group, they'll be able to view only that path. I want other users to view other directories, how is that possible?

Please help me, It's really important for me, as I've many game-servers to handle on a VPS, working with different developers.

Comment: just a remark `ssh` (and `sftp`) have nothing to do with `vsftpd` who have a configuration of its onw (`/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`)

Comment: Do you want some sense of *security* with an unencrypted FTP? Is it in some SOHO LAN, or?

Comment: It is a Ubuntu VPS, security can be left out if the thing works.

Answer (score 1):

Change `ChrootDirectory /home/shooter/shooter/mods` to `ChrootDirectory %h` doing so you can restrict users of that groups to their home directory.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group shooter
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Follow this for write issue [sftp_with_write_issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308543/how-can-i-restrict-ssh-user-to-particular-directory-with-write-permission)